# Java's UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, writer

I have this code:

```
BufferedWriter w = Files.newWriter(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
w.newLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("\"").append("éééé").append("\";")
w.write(sb.toString());
```

But it ain't work. In the end my file hasn't an UTF-8 encoding. I tried to do this when writing:

```
w.write(new String(sb.toString().getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII), "UTF8"));
```

It made question marks appear everywhere in the file...
I found that there was a bug regarding the recognition of the initial BOM charcater ([http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058](http://Bug)), so I tried using the BOMInputStream class. But `bomIn.hasBOM()` always returns false, so I guess my problem is not BOM related maybe?

Do you know how I can make my file encoded in UTF-8? Was the problem solved in Java 8?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what your actual problem is. Please show the real code, the input and the output. UTF-8 works fine in Java, and of course `sb.toString().getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII)` will produce a lot of question marks, as US_ASCII only supports characters 0 .. 127, everything else is invalid and replaced with a question mark. Also use of BOM with UTF-8 is discouraged.

Comment: Sure it works. With your `BufferedWriter` created, you can just do `w.write("Hello, äöå"); w.close();` and I guarantee the file will be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: "It made question marks appear everywhere in the file..." - so the problem is actually in where you view the file.

Comment: Well, `w.write("Hello, äöå");` gave me: `Hello, Ã¤Ã¶Ã¥`

Comment: That is a problem of **reading** the file with the wrong encoding, not a problem of writing UTF-8. If I paste `Hello, Ã¤Ã¶Ã¥` into notepad++ with encoding set to ANSI, and then switch it to encoding UTF-8, it will show `Hello, äöå` as expected.

Comment: Re your edit. You are writing UTF-8 correctly, so you are just reading it incorrectly. Side note: the `new String` in `w.write(new String(sb.toString()));` is entirely unnecessary. I'd even go as far as saying your use of `StringBuilder` is unnecessary; just write directly into the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot; forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing UTF-8 correctly in your first example (although you're redundantly creating a String from a String)

The problem is that the viewer or tool you're using to view the file doesn't read the file as UTF-8.

Don't mix in ASCII, that just converts all the non-ASCII bytes to question marks.